Startup Scripts on Kubuntu 24.04
I have made a clean install of Kubuntu 24.04, moving over from 22.04. I have one startup script that I want to run to update all my Git repos on boot. This script has been used for several years while on 22.04 with no issues. It is no longer working on 24.04 and I am unsure why. I have included my desktop entry file below. Has anyone experienced this issue and found a solution?
[Desktop Entry]
Comment[en_AU]=
Comment=
Exec=bash /home/<username>/.config/old-autostart-scripts/git.sh
GenericName[en_AU]=
GenericName=
Icon=dialog-scripts
MimeType=
Name[en_AU]=git.sh
Name=git.sh
Path=
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=true
TerminalOptions=\s--noclose
Type=Application
X-DBUS-ServiceName=
X-DBUS-StartupType=none
X-KDE-AutostartScript=true
X-KDE-SubstituteUID=false
X-KDE-Username=

The script works if I run it manually in terminal.
The .desktop file is in ~/.config/autostart.
The directory permissions for both autostart and old-autostart-scripts is drwxrwxr-x.
The .desktop file has permissions -rw------- and the actual script has permissions -rwxrwxrwx.
I also have yakuake autostart on boot and that has no issues.
EDIT: For completeness I have included the script I am attempting to run on startup. Note that the script will run without fault if I manually run it, i.e. bash .config/old_autostart_scripts/git.sh.
#!/bin/bash

nm-online

gh personal

repositories=(
    "/home/<username>/Documents/API/Canvas/"
    "/home/<username>/Documents/API/GitHub/"
    "/home/<username>/Documents/Script Tools/"
    "/home/<username>/Documents/Config Files/"
    "/home/<username>/Documents/Tipon"
    "/home/<username>/Documents/DB_Backups"
    "/home/<username>/Documents/Learning Java"
    "/home/<username>/Documents/University/"
    "/home/<username>/texmf"
    "/home/<username>/Documents/CV/"
)

for (( i=0 ; i < ${#repositories[@]} ; i++ ))
do
    git -C "${repositories[$i]}" pull origin master
done

gh uni

repositories=(
    "/home/<username>/Documents/canvasapi/"
    "/home/<username>/Documents/periodic-logistic"
)

for (( i=0 ; i < ${#repositories[@]} ; i++ ))
do
    git -C "${repositories[$i]}" pull origin master
done

gh personal

# First change directories and set variables for current day date and
# yesterday's date.
cd /home/<username>/Documents/DB_Backups/Tipon

# Count the number of files in the directory.
file_count=$(ls -q *.sql | wc -l)

if [ $file_count == 0 ]
then
    # If there is no previous backup just copy over the serve backup and
    # add and commit it.
    scp <username>@<ssh_host>:*.sql .
    backup=$(echo $(ls *.sql | sed -e 's/\.sql$//'))
    git add .
    git commit -m "Updated TipOn backup to ${backup}"
    git push origin master
    echo "Updated backup to ${backup}."
else
    # If there is a previous backup copy over the current server backup and
    # check if this differs from the current one. If it differs add and
    # commit it, otherwise do nothing.
    prev_backup=$(echo $(ls *.sql | sed -e 's/\.sql$//'))
    scp <username>@<ssh_host>:*.sql .
    file_count=$(ls -1 *.sql | wc -l)
    if [ $file_count -gt 1 ]
    then
        rm -f ${prev_backup}.sql
        new_backup=$(echo $(ls *.sql | sed -e 's/\.sql$//'))
        git add .
        git commit -m "Updated TipOn backup to ${new_backup}"
        git push origin master
        echo "Updated backup to ${new_backup}."
    else
        echo "Backup already up to date."
    fi
fi

EDIT: Ironically, after I submitted the previous edit I decided to have a look at this issue again. I rain the script manually and to my surprise it claimed that the backup file it is supposed to update was already updated. So I added
vim -c 'wq' /home/<username>/test.txt

to the script to test if it is in fact running. After I rebooted my machine I indeed had a file /home/<username>/test.txt. So I guess the script is actually running on startup but for some reason it is not opening a Konsole to run with the expected behaviour, i.e. leave the terminal open after running.

Does the script work if you run it with bash /home/<username>/.config/old-autostart-scripts/git.sh from a terminal? Have you placed the .desktop file in ~/.config/autostart? What are its permissions (default should be 600 and owned by your user)?

@kos yes the script works if I run it manually in terminal. Yes, the .desktop file is in ~/.config/autostart. The directory permissions for both autostart and old-autostart-scripts is drwxrwxr-x. The .dekstop file has permissions -rw------- and the actual script has permissions -rwxrwxrwx. I also have yakuake autostart on boot and that has no issues.

Is the .desktop the same you were using on 22.04? Or did you generate it again via "Automatic startup" (or whatever it's called in english - I mean the GUI to add startup scripts)? If the former, I would try and generate a new startup script via the GUI and compare its entries to your .desktop files'. E.g. (diff <(sort /path/to/old/desktop/file) <(sort /path/to/new/desktop/file)). Maybe you need to adjust some entries for some reason (although since you're at it you might as well just create a new startup script for your script through the GUI and see if it works)

If that doesn't help please post the script so that we can look at it (redacting private git stuff)

FWIW, I'm hitting a similar issue (autostart a .sh) in Kubuntu 24.04 and Manjaro 24.0.7.  The only common ground I can find is both use KDE Plasma (but different versions).

@Bernmeister Yes I am still experiencing the issue. I have tried creating a new .desktop file and reusing my previous file. Neither provides a working solution.
